# Location Updates Not Regular

Tags: android, gps, location, android-gps

I am developing a distance based app which requires regular distance updates the app works fine if the device has internet but if the device does not have connectivity in that case even if the GPS is on and I am moving it fails to update the location on the OnLocationChanged Listener swiftly as required

Registering The Location Listener

```
LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[]{
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)

 mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[1]);
```

LocationListener

```
private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {
    Location mLastLocation;

    public LocationListener(String provider) {
        Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
        mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
        mLastLocation.set(location);
        mLocationController.updateLastKnownLocation(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
    }
}

LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[]{
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
};
```

I am using this Location Listener

Comment: Jatan, please share us the code you have written so that we may have a look at it and possibly help.

Comment: @Raman I have posted the code I am using

Comment: @Jatan please post also `requestLocationUpdates(...)`

Comment: @Raman I have posted the requestLocationUpdates